# Add icon to icomoon font without changing unicode

Tags: css, unicode, icons

Is there a way to add an icon to an existing icomoon font though the [icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) without changing the CSS unicode?

I just need to add one icon and I'm not quite sure where each and every pseudo element for where icomoon icons are called. I know I could manually parse through the litany of less sheets, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://icomoon.io/#faq/codes

Basically, you should either import your "selection.json" file or a previously generated SVG font.